# Python: How to iterate through set of files based on file names?

Tags: python, bash, perl, file, loops

I have a set of files named like this:

```
qd-p64-dZP-d64-z8-8nn.q         
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-1nn.q             qq-p8-dZP-d8-z1-2nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-2nn.q             qq-p8-dZP-d8-z1-4nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-4nn.q             qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-1nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-1nn.q            qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-2nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-2nn.q            qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-4nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-4nn.q            qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-8nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-8nn.q            qq-p8-dZP-d8-z1-8nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-8nn.q             qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-1nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-1nn.q             qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-2nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-2nn.q             qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-4nn.q 
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-4nn.q             qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-8nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-8nn.q             qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-1nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-1nn.q            qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-2nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-2nn.q            qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-4nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-4nn.q            qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-8nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-8nn.q            qq-p8-dZP-d8-z4-1nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z4-1nn.q             qq-p8-dZP-d8-z4-2nn.q
qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z4-2nn.q             qq-p8-dZP-d8-z4-4nn.q
```

The information to iterate is given in the file names, for example:

Fix

```
dZP, 1nn, z2,
```

and vary

```
d
```

with values

```
{d8, d16, d32 d64}
```

Then, increase z value to get

```
dZP, 1nn, z4
```

and vary d again

```
{d8, d16, d32 d64}
```

Once I'm able to iterate like this I need to do some information processing     from the files.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: What about the `2nn` and `4nn` files? What about `qd` and `qp`? All the example files here are `d8`? What about `p8` (that you didn't mention at all)? You need to provide a much clearer indication of what you are actually trying to do here. Are you just looking to iterate through the files in a particular order of certain filename fields?

Comment: @EtanReisner, yes I also need to use 2nn and 4nn, I just wrote the example using previous values,, and yes I need to iterate through the files in a particular order of certain filename fields, I can't figure out how to browse through the file names in order to loop over the whole set of fields.

Comment: Are you starting with a list of files and trying to extrat those pieces out of it, or starting with those different values and trying to generate all the file names?

Comment: What about the other parts of the file names, like the `qd-` and `qq-` prefixes and the extension `.q`? How do they affect the order?

Comment: @martineau I already have files with those names, my task is to  extract information from them, so I need to browse all of them in search of the information desired. It has specific order, lets say for nn=1, d=PZ, z=2, vary d, with values d=8, d=16, d=32, d=64, and extract the information needed, then increase z=4 to get nn=1, d=PZ, z=4, and vary d with values d=8, d=16, d=3, d=64.... and so on. From answers given I would think that Im going to generate file names, then search in folder for file name generated and finally extract the information from each file. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @berce, I think is better to generate file names and then search for each name file generated in my directory, and finally extract information from each file.

Comment: @Diego: Although you could do it by generating every possible filename and searching for it in the folder, seems like it would be quicker to just sort the filenames that exist in the folder into the desired processing order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a good task for a generator. I just did it for d, z, and n, but it should be easy enough to generalize to all of your filename fields:

```
def filename_generator():
    l1 = ['d8', 'd16', 'd32', 'd64']
    l2 = ['z1', 'z2', 'z4', ,'z8', 'z16', 'z32']
    l3 = ['1nn', '2nn', '4nn', '8nn']
    for n in l3:
        for z in l2:
            for d in l1:
                yield '%s-%s-%s.q' % (d, z, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could something like the following. It may not be *exactly* what you want, since you've left some important details out of your question, but I've attempted to write it in a way to make it easy for you to change as necessary depending on what you really want.

In a nutshell, what it does is use the `re` module break each filename up into "fields" with the numeric value found in each. These values are assigned corresponding names it a temporary dictionary, which is then used to create a `namedtuple` of the values with the desired field precedence. Other parts of the filename are ignored.

The initial filename list can be obtained from the file system using `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob()`.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re

filenames = ['qd-p64-dZP-d64-z8-8nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-1nn.q',
             'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-2nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-4nn.q',
             'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-1nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-2nn.q',
             'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-4nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-8nn.q',
             'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-8nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-1nn.q',
             'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-2nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-4nn.q',
             'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-8nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-1nn.q',
             'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-2nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-4nn.q',
             'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-8nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z4-1nn.q',
             'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z4-2nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z1-2nn.q',
             'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z1-4nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-1nn.q',
             'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-2nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-4nn.q',
             'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-8nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z1-8nn.q',
             'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-1nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-2nn.q',
             'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-4nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-8nn.q',
             'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-1nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-2nn.q',
             'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-4nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-8nn.q',
             'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z4-1nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z4-2nn.q',
             'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z4-4nn.q']

filename_order = ('p', 'd', 'z', 'nn')  # order fields occur in the filenames
fieldname_order = ('z', 'd', 'p', 'nn')  # desired field sort order
OrderedTuple = namedtuple('OrderedTuple', fieldname_order)

def keyfunc(filename):
    values = [int(value) for value in re.findall(r'-\D*(\d+)', filename)]
    parts = dict(zip(filename_order, values))
    return OrderedTuple(**parts)

filenames.sort(key=keyfunc)  # sort filename list in-place
```

Resulting order of filenames in list:

```
['qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-1nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-2nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z1-2nn.q',
 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-4nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z1-4nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z1-8nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z1-8nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-1nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-1nn.q',
 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-2nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-2nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-4nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-4nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z2-8nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z2-8nn.q',
 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z4-1nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z4-1nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z4-2nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z4-2nn.q', 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z4-4nn.q',
 'qd-p64-dZP-d64-z8-8nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-1nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-1nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-2nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-2nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-4nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-4nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z16-8nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z16-8nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-1nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-1nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-2nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-2nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-4nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-4nn.q', 'qd-p8-dPZ-d8-z32-8nn.q',
 'qq-p8-dZP-d8-z32-8nn.q']
```